# Searching for a List of Strings start with a particular String from a sorted ArrayList in java

Tags: java, string, search

Here I have an English wordlist :  (For example )

```
account

angel

apple

application

black

...
```

And I want to search for strings which start with a particular String. For example : `the result for "ap" should be { apple, application }.`

It can be easily implemented by sequence search based solution to return a set corresponding Strings. But out there still have algorithms stronger than sequence search but they return a String only. So, Any ideal to return a set corresponding String from the ArrayList faster than sequence search based one?

Thanks!

Comment: TRIE algorithm seems to be designed for the job: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie
And here is some implementation: http://pathakalgo.blogspot.cz/2012/11/trie-data-structure-implementation-in.html

Comment: before you search for a faster version: have you profiled the existing code and found it to be an actual bottleneck?

Comment: You can also use a slightly modified version of binary search that returns the last serach position, no matter if the string was found or not. From there, you can go upwards in the array until the initial string is greater than your search string.

Comment: TRIE is not an algorithm, but a *data structure*. If you want to hold on to your ArrayList, binary search is very efficient.

Comment: Thanks, Trie should be a great ideal!
But I thought to a prefix tree before this post.
A prefix tree require us to pay cost to build the tree while the arraylist already sorted itself. Beside, instead of return a set of String, we can find the first and the last index of strings which contain the particular String, this would faster than travel each leaf in a tree. There will be algorithms can do it fast, I think.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The standard API already has a [binary search](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#binarySearch%28java.util.List,%20T%29) that allows doing this fine:

```
    int index = Collections.binarySearch(list, key);
    if (index < 0) {
        index = -(index + 1);
    }
    List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
    while (index < list.size()) {
        String s = list.get(index);
        if (s.startsWith(key)) {
            result.add(s);
        }
        else {
            break;
        }
        index++;
    }
```

Comment: But will the standard API return the first element contain the particular String?

Comment: @ThucHung Did you study the Javadoc, as linked to in this answer?

Comment: Sorry, I have never read Javadoc before. I will check it now.

Comment: Thank you @JB Nizet, you help me find out the answer.

Comment: @JB Nizet : thank you, I implemented your code to my application and it cause to a great speed.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly a simple binary search will do this very quickly:

```
int startPoint = 0;
int endPoint = list.length()-1;

do {
   int mid = (startPoint+endPoint)/2;
   int cmp = list.get().compareTo(str);
   if (cmp > 0) {
      startPoint = mid;
   } else if (cmp < 0) {
      endPoint = mid;
   } else {
       startPoint = mid;
   }

} while (! list.get(startPoint).startsWith(str) && startPoint<endPoint-1);
```

Now just scan in both directions from startPoint adding strings to your Set until you find ones that don't match.

Comment: Ummm ... what if no list item starts with str?

Comment: True, I added a check for that. This is what I get for throwing something down quickly.